# Call to powershell process from inlined C#

Tags: c#, powershell, tfs, continuous-integration, vnext

I have a PowerShell script that execute some inlined C# code like this:

```
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp
[AnalyzeHelper.AnalyzeDirectories]::CheckPath("XXX")
```

In that C# code I would like to output to my PowerShell output.
So in my C# I have implemented:

```
public static void CheckPath(string path)
{
    WriteOutput("Begin CheckPath");
}

private static void WriteOutput(string text)
{
  using (PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
  {
    powerShellInstance.AddCommand("Write-Host").AddParameter("string", text).Invoke();
  }
}
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work. It actually just hang in the invoke call.

Comment: Why don't you just return the string as a result of your C# code and output it with powershell itself?

Comment: The sample is quite simplified as I have more logic in the C# part, and would like several log statements to the output from there. So it is not just one string but several.

Comment: Probably this thread could help https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/abc255ff-cee0-4941-a88c-c095f2110506/c-powershell-and-console-applications-how-to-handle-input-during-processing?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Shouldn't that just be `powerShellInstance.AddCommand("Write-Host").AddParameter(text).Invoke();` ?

Comment: Just tried and it didn't work as well. But I found that I instead can do it delegate style which is a solution for my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that PowerShell supports delegates so solution was quite simple.
I called like this:

```
[Action[string]]$action = {param($message) Write-Host "$message"}
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp
[AnalyzeStringLibraries.AnalyzeStrings]::CheckPath("XXX", $action)
```

Then in the C# I can do like this:

```
public static void CheckPath(string path, Action<string> writeToHost)
{
    writeToHost("Begin CheckPath");
}
```

Comment: Nice; note that PowerShell treats script blocks (`{ ... }`) as delegates in method calls on demand, so you could even have called `[AnalyzeStringLibraries.AnalyzeStrings]::CheckPath("XXX", { param($message) Write-Host "$message" })` directly.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. With my C# dev background I keep being surpised of the power of PowerShell.